# Eliminar parênteses com php

Tags: php

Como faço para eliminar os ***parênteses*** e o ***traço*** dessa variavel em `php` ?

```
$var = " ( 1 ) - ( 2 ) ";
```

Resultado final:

Seria um array separando os numeros, exemplo:

```
 x[0]; -> 1
 x[1]; -> 2
```

Eu gostaria que fosse retirado os ***parenteses*** e o ***traço*** e guardado em arrays apenas os números.

Comment: No caso (1) - (2) está vindo como string ?

Comment: Esta guardado dentro da variavel $var e esta como string. $var = "(1) - (2)";

Comment: Como seria o resultado final? edite sua pergunta e coloque para entender , como seria a resposta.

Comment: eu editei o post

Answer (score 6):

Pode usar `preg_match` assim:

```
<?php

$var = '(1) - (2)';

preg_match('#\((\d+)\) - \((\d+)\)#', $var, $output);

array_shift($output); //Remove o primeiro item, pois não vai usa-lo

print_r($output);

echo 'Primeiro número: ', $output[0], PHP_EOL;
echo 'Segundo número: ', $output[1], PHP_EOL;
```

Irá exibir isto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Primeiro número: 1
Segundo número: 2
```

Então basta usar assim:

```
echo $output[0]; //Pega o primeiro numero
echo $output[1]; //Pega o segundo numero
```

Veja o resultado no [ideone](http://ideone.com/zy8L66)

Ou pode usar `preg_match_all` para pegar tudo o que estiver no "caminho":

```
<?php

$var = '(1) - (2) - (3)';

preg_match_all('#\((\d+)\)#', $var, $output);

$resultado = $output[1];//Pega apenas os números

print_r($resultado);
```

Irá exibir isto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Então basta usar assim:

```
echo $resultado[0]; //Pega o primeiro numero
echo $resultado[1]; //Pega o segundo numero
echo $resultado[2]; //Pega o terceiro numero
```

Veja o resultado no [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ezk1Ks)

Se ainda tiver duvidas de como usar arrays, recomendo aprender o básico:

- `for() {}`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php
- arrays: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

E depois que aprender o básico segue a documentação sobre as funções usadas:

- `preg_match`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php
- `preg_match_all`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php
- `array_shift`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php

Comment: Estou perguntando, pois eu fiz esse teste print_r($output[1]); , Isso deve me retornar apenas o valor da posição 1 do array, mas esta me retornando tudo.

Comment: Retornou isso: Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Comment: @abduzeedo editei a resposta novamente e adicionei alguns links para lhe ajudar :D

Comment: Que legal, no caso esse preg_match_all, serviria para tirar tambem uma palavra da frente do numero ? exemplo: amigo(1) - amigo(2). Daria oara tirar a palavra amigo e os parentes ?

Comment: @abduzeedo não precisa usar o preg_match_all para isto, basta alterar a RegEx entre o `#...#`, faça assim `preg_match('#amigo\((\d+)\) - amigo\((\d+)\)#', $var, $output);`... O com`preg_match_all('#\((\d+)\)#', $var, $output);`, não precisa, ele reconhece somente os numeros.